# How to register users in Django REST framework?

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-models, django-rest-framework

I'm coding a REST API with [Django REST framework](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/). The API will be the backend of a social mobile app. After following the tutorial, I can serialise all my models and I am able to create new resources and update them.

I'm using AuthToken for authentication.

My question is:

Once I have the `/users` resource, I want the app user to be able to register. So, is it better to have a separate resource like `/register` or allow anonymous users to POST to `/users` a new resource?

Also, some guidance about permissions would be great.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30085996/djangorestframework-registering-a-user-difference-between-userserializer-save/30087194#30087194

Answer (score 54, accepted):

I went ahead and made my own custom view for handling registration since my serializer doesn't expect to show/retrieve the password. I made the url different from the /users resource.

My url conf:

```
url(r'^users/register', 'myapp.views.create_auth'),
```

My view:

```
@api_view(['POST'])
def create_auth(request):
    serialized = UserSerializer(data=request.DATA)
    if serialized.is_valid():
        User.objects.create_user(
            serialized.init_data['email'],
            serialized.init_data['username'],
            serialized.init_data['password']
        )
        return Response(serialized.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
    else:
        return Response(serialized._errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

I may be wrong, but it doesn't seem like you'll need to limit permissions on this view since you'd want unauthenticated requests ...

Comment: wanted to point out that the reason Cahlan is using init_data instead of data is because `UserSerializer` doesn't read/write passwords. after calling `is_valid()`, it's fine if someone wants to use `serialized.data['email']` and `serialized.data['username']` but password will only be available in `serialized.init_data['password']`. Also the order of email and username params should be switched (at least in Django 1.6). or you can always pass named parameters e.g. `User.objects.create_user(email='me@example.com', username='admin', password='admin123')`

Comment: Just curious wouldn't this solution be insecure ? this means that any body with knowledge of this endpoint and keep registering users ?

Comment: @DjangoRocks you are right, but you can use [throttling](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/throttling/)

Comment: @yossi The solution is to use CAPTCHA. Throttling doesn't completely address the issue.

Comment: is there any way to insert username as email in serialized data?

Answer (score 122):

Django REST Framework 3 [allow](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/1-serialization/#creating-a-serializer-class) override `create` method in serializers:

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model # If used custom user model

UserModel = get_user_model()


class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    password = serializers.CharField(write_only=True)

    def create(self, validated_data):

        user = UserModel.objects.create_user(
            username=validated_data['username'],
            password=validated_data['password'],
        )

        return user

    class Meta:
        model = UserModel
        # Tuple of serialized model fields (see link [2])
        fields = ( "id", "username", "password", )
```

Serialized fields for classes inherited from `ModelSerializer` must be declared patently in `Meta` for Django Rest Framework [v3.5](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/community/3.5-announcement/#modelserializer-fields-and-exclude) and newest.

File **api.py**:

```
from rest_framework import permissions
from rest_framework.generics import CreateAPIView
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model # If used custom user model

from .serializers import UserSerializer


class CreateUserView(CreateAPIView):

    model = get_user_model()
    permission_classes = [
        permissions.AllowAny # Or anon users can't register
    ]
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
```

Comment: This is the fastest and most up to date way to do this.

Comment: Why do you use user.set_password instead of setting the password keyword parameter in UserModel.objects.create()?

Comment: Ah nevermind I see you didn't use create_user which handles password hashing

Comment: how can one add extra fields to the registration?

Comment: Hi @Dunaevsky Maxim, I open a question in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68171987/how-to-print-content-inside-userserializer-type-django-rest-framework would you like to take a look ?

Comment: you couldn't save non hashed password

Answer (score 50):

The simplest solution, working in DRF 3.x:

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('id', 'username', 'password', 'email', 'first_name', 'last_name')
        write_only_fields = ('password',)
        read_only_fields = ('id',)

    def create(self, validated_data):
        user = User.objects.create(
            username=validated_data['username'],
            email=validated_data['email'],
            first_name=validated_data['first_name'],
            last_name=validated_data['last_name']
        )

        user.set_password(validated_data['password'])
        user.save()

        return user
```

No need for other changes, just make sure that unauthenticated users have the permission to create a new user object.

`write_only_fields` will make sure passwords (actually: their hash we store) are not displayed, while the overwritten `create` method ensures that the password is not stored in clear text, but as a hash.

Comment: Sorry if I'm wrong, but is it explicitely needed to override the create method? I tried just adding the write_only_fields and read_only_fields and it worked as I expected it to. Any clues?

Comment: @dabad If you do that, the password will probably get stored in clear text in the database, something you absolutely don't want. The only line the custom `create` method adds is the Django-native `set_password` method to generate a hash for the password.

Comment: you can use `extra_kwargs = {'password': {'write_only': True}}` instead of `write_only_fields` for django versions greater than 3.0

Answer (score 42):

I typically treat the User view just like any other API endpoint that required authorization, except I just override the view class's permission set with my own for POST (aka create). I typically use this pattern:

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from rest_framework import viewsets
from rest_framework.permissions import AllowAny


class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = get_user_model().objects
    serializer_class = UserSerializer

    def get_permissions(self):
        if self.request.method == 'POST':
            self.permission_classes = (AllowAny,)

        return super(UserViewSet, self).get_permissions()
```

For good measure, here is the serializer I typically use with it:

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = get_user_model()
        fields = (
            'id',
            'username',
            'password',
            'email',
            ...,
        )
        extra_kwargs = {
            'password': {'write_only': True},
        }

    def create(self, validated_data):
        user = get_user_model().objects.create_user(**validated_data)
        return user

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        if 'password' in validated_data:
            password = validated_data.pop('password')
            instance.set_password(password)
        return super(UserSerializer, self).update(instance, validated_data)
```

djangorestframework 3.3.x / Django 1.8.x

Comment: I looked at all the answers and it seems that everybody suggest to do Model-saving logic in the serialiser.
I reckon this is against the Django MVVM guidelines where the 'controller' logic should be in the view

Answer (score 27):

I updated Cahlan's answer to support custom user models from Django 1.5 and return the user's ID in the response.

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

from rest_framework import status, serializers
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view
from rest_framework.response import Response

class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = get_user_model()

@api_view(['POST'])
def register(request):
    VALID_USER_FIELDS = [f.name for f in get_user_model()._meta.fields]
    DEFAULTS = {
        # you can define any defaults that you would like for the user, here
    }
    serialized = UserSerializer(data=request.DATA)
    if serialized.is_valid():
        user_data = {field: data for (field, data) in request.DATA.items() if field in VALID_USER_FIELDS}
        user_data.update(DEFAULTS)
        user = get_user_model().objects.create_user(
            **user_data
        )
        return Response(UserSerializer(instance=user).data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
    else:
        return Response(serialized._errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Comment: How are you handling the password here?

Comment: **DANGER** If I'm not mistaken, this code allows submission of `is_superuser` and `is_staff` values. Allowed fields should be specified explicitly IMO, as shown in the other examples.

Answer (score 16):

@cpury above suggested using `write_only_fields` option. This however did not work for me in DRF 3.3.3

In [DRF 3.0](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/topics/3.0-announcement/#serializers) the `write_only_fields` option on ModelSerializer has been moved to PendingDeprecation and in [DRF 3.2](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/topics/3.2-announcement/) replaced with a more generic extra_kwargs:

`extra_kwargs = {'password': {'write_only': True}}`

Answer (score 10):

All of the answers so far create the user, then update the user's password. This results in two DB writes. To avoid an extra unnecessary DB write, set the user's password before saving it:

```
from rest_framework.serializers import ModelSerializer

class UserSerializer(ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = User

    def create(self, validated_data):
        user = User(**validated_data)
        # Hash the user's password.
        user.set_password(validated_data['password'])
        user.save()
        return user
```

Comment: Good point. Worse still, doing it in two steps seems like a security concern. Without it being done in an atomic transaction, if there's an error between where the user is created and the user is saved with a hashed password then the data saved in the DB is in cleartext

Answer (score 6):

While there are many answers to this question, none of the answers (as of my writing) addresses the critical security concern, the password validation that is defined in `settings.AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS`. So it is possible to create a password like `'1'` which must not be acceptable. So I have fixed this major security issue. Here is my solution:

### In serializers.py:

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.contrib.auth.password_validation import validate_password
from rest_framework import serializers


class SignupSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = get_user_model()
        fields = ['username', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'password', ]
        extra_kwargs = {
            'password': {'write_only': True}
        }

    def validate_password(self, value):
        validate_password(value)
        return value

    def create(self, validated_data):
        user = get_user_model()(**validated_data)

        user.set_password(validated_data['password'])
        user.save()

        return user
```

### In views.py:

```
from rest_framework import mixins, viewsets
from rest_framework.permissions import AllowAny, IsAuthenticated

from . import forms, serializers


class SignupViewSet(mixins.CreateModelMixin,
                    viewsets.GenericViewSet):
    permission_classes = [AllowAny]
    serializer_class = serializers.SignupSerializer
```

### API Response:

Now, if you try with a simple password like `'1'`, this response will be returned automatically:

```
{
    "password": [
        "This password is too short. It must contain at least 8 characters.",
        "This password is too common.",
        "This password is entirely numeric."
    ]
}
```

In case of a password like `'12345678'`, the response is:

```
{
    "password": [
        "This password is too common.",
        "This password is entirely numeric."
    ]
}
```

In this way, the end-client will know exactly what else are required for the password to be valid.

Comment: Could you explain, where `validate_password` serializer's method will be called? Should not we call that inside body of `create` method by ourselves?

Comment: `validate_password` will be called before `create` method. `create` method is only called if validation is successful. So `create` method has `validated_data` argument.

Comment: So is it correct that we can declare a method with `def validate_[any serializer field here](self, value):` and it will be called before creating?

Comment: Yes, it should be called before creating.

Answer (score 5):

A little late to the party, but might help someone who do not want to write more lines of code.

We can user the `super` method to achieve this.

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    password = serializers.CharField(
          write_only=True,
    )

    class Meta:
       model = User
       fields = ('password', 'username', 'first_name', 'last_name',)

    def create(self, validated_data):
        user = super(UserSerializer, self).create(validated_data)
        if 'password' in validated_data:
              user.set_password(validated_data['password'])
              user.save()
        return user
```

Comment: will I have to set a different url for the registerations?

Comment: Here's an extra bit for those wanting to keep the password field hidden :     

class UserSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):

    password = serializers.CharField(
          write_only=True,
          style={'input_type': 'password', 'placeholder': 'Password'},
    )

Answer (score 5):

A Python 3, Django 2 & Django REST Framework viewset based implementation:

File: **serializers.py**

```
from rest_framework.serializers import ModelSerializers
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

UserModel = get_user_model()

class UserSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    password = serializers.CharField(write_only=True)

    def create(self, validated_data):
        user = UserModel.objects.create_user(
            username=validated_data['username'],
            password=validated_data['password'],
            first_name=validated_data['first_name'],
            last_name=validated_data['last_name'],
        )
        return user

    class Meta:
        model = UserModel
        fields = ('password', 'username', 'first_name', 'last_name',)
```

File **views.py**:

```
from rest_framework.viewsets import GenericViewSet
from rest_framework.mixins import CreateModelMixin
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from .serializers import UserSerializer

class CreateUserView(CreateModelMixin, GenericViewSet):
    queryset = get_user_model().objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
```

File **urls.py**

```
from rest_framework.routers import DefaultRouter
from .views import CreateUserView

router = DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'createuser', CreateUserView)

urlpatterns = router.urls
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# This work nicely, but serializer will reamain as it is, like

from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.contrib.auth.password_validation import validate_password
from rest_framework import serializers


class SignupSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = get_user_model()
        fields = ['username', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'password', ]
        extra_kwargs = {
            'password': {'write_only': True}
        }

    def validate_password(self, value):
        validate_password(value)
        return value

    def create(self, validated_data):
        user = get_user_model()(**validated_data)

        user.set_password(validated_data['password'])
        user.save()

        return user
```

## To simplify, modify your view to

```
from rest_framework import mixins, viewsets

from rest_framework.permissions import AllowAny, IsAuthenticated

from . import forms, serializers
class SignUpUserView(mixins.CreateModelMixin, viewsets.GenericViewSet):
    permission_classes = [AllowAny]
    queryset = get_user_model().objects.all() #Add this line
    serializer_class = SignUpSerializer
```