# How to autologin after signup using Django Rest Framework?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm using Django 1.9 and DRF 3.0, here is my view:

```
class UserList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = MyUser.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticatedOrCreate,)

    def create(request, *args, **kwargs):
        user = MyUser.objects.create(
            user_name=request['user_name'],
            email=request['email'],
        )
        user.set_password(request['password'])
        user.save()
        login(request, user)
        return user
```

and my serializers

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = MyUser
        fields = ("id", "email", "user_name", "password", "user_avatar", "user_gender", "user_point", "user_details", "user_register_time")
        write_only_fields = ("password",)
        read_only_fields = ("id", "user_avatar", "user_gender", "user_point", "user_details", "user_register_time")
```

and Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 149, in get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 147, in get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 58, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 68, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 466, in dispatch
    response = self.handle_exception(exc)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 463, in dispatch
    response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/rest_framework/generics.py", line 246, in post
    return self.create(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/windson/uni/srv/unicooo/www/api/views.py", line 105, in create
    user_name=request['user_name'],
TypeError: 'UserList' object is not subscriptable
```

**And my perious version is like this:**

```
class UserList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = MyUser.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticatedOrCreate,)
```

and my serializers

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = MyUser
        fields = ("id", "email", "user_name", "password", "user_avatar", "user_gender", "user_point", "user_details", "user_register_time")
        write_only_fields = ("password",)
        read_only_fields = ("id", "user_avatar", "user_gender", "user_point", "user_details", "user_register_time")

    def create(request, *args, **kwargs):
        user = MyUser.objects.create(
            user_name=request['user_name'],
            email=request['email'],
        )
        user.set_password(request['password'])
        user.save()
        return user
```

I want to login user after they sign up, so I rewrite the create method and using login() method, and the error message is "'UserList' object is not subscriptable", how to fix it? Thanks.

Comment: can you show the  traceback

Comment: You error and your code are inconsistent: the create is for `UserSerializer` and yet it's applied to `UserList`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This finally work:

```
class UserList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = MyUser.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticatedOrCreate,)

    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        self.perform_create(serializer)
        headers = self.get_success_headers(serializer.data)
        new_user = authenticate(email=request.POST.get('email'),
            password=request.POST.get('password'),
            )
        if new_user is not None:
            if new_user.is_active:
                django_login(request, new_user)
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED, headers=headers)
```

Comment: what does your urls.py look like? what does the serializer look like? and finally what does the registration request body look like?

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that you are returning a user object directly, I think it should be as follows:

```
 from rest_framework import status
 class UserList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = MyUser.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticatedOrCreate,)

    def create(request, *args, **kwargs):
        user = MyUser.objects.create(
            user_name=request.POST.get('user_name'),
            email=request.POST.get('email'),
        )
        user.set_password(request.POST.get('password'))
        user.save()
        user = authenticate(user_name=request.POST.get('user_name'), password=request.POST.get('password'))
        login(request, user)
        serializer = UserSerializer(user)
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

**Update**
I've updated the code above regarding this from the documentation.

> Calling authenticate() first
>
> When you’re manually logging a user in, you must successfully
>   authenticate the user with authenticate() before you call login().
>   authenticate() sets an attribute on the User noting which
>   authentication backend successfully authenticated that user (see the
>   backends documentation for details), and this information is needed
>   later during the login process. An error will be raised if you try to
>   login a user object retrieved from the database directly.
>   https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/auth/default/#how-to-log-a-user-in

Comment: Still not working, TypeError: 'UserList' object is not subscriptable

Comment: check the updates and if the error changes, please show the traceback. Updated again

Comment: No tradeback this time, I can create user now but when I redirect to another page, still not authentication, I post username, password, email using ajax. and I just get them back in my http response without response cookies.

Comment: I've updated my answer again. But what do you mean by > response cookies<

Comment: not working, and the password save to the database become decrypt.

Comment: You mean encrypted, yes this make sense. As long as it returned 201 so it login successfully. Make sure you are using `django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware` in `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES` inside settings.py or similar middleware. So what is wrong now exactly? you can change serializer.data and return anything else if you want.

Comment: Forgive my poor english, I'd change the code to what I used to write. I follow Maxim Dunaevsky in this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16857450/how-to-register-users-in-django-rest-framework. It work fine and the password is encrypted, but when I change my code like yours, the password become not encrypted, and the user still not auth.I'm using session auth in django, and I think login() method should create cookies and session for user automatic. It returned 201 so create successfully but haven't login yet.

Comment: do you set AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'yourapp.MyUser' in settings.py? as the only difference I can figure is that it uses `get_user_model` which is preferably should be used