# create new user in django gives not hashed password

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to create users using post request within django rest framework.

Here is my serializer code:

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    favorites = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(many=True, queryset=Favorite.objects.all())
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('id', 'username','password','favorites')
        extra_kwargs = {
            'password': {
                'write_only': True,
            },
            'confirm_password': {
                'write_only': True,
            },
            'favorites':
            {
                'read_only': True,
            },
        }

    def create(self, validated_data):
        return User.objects.create(**validated_data)
```

for create method i used also this implementation:

```
def create(self, validated_data):
    user = User(username=validated_data['username'])
    user.set_password(validated_data['password'])
    user.save()
    return user
```

In my admin panel it says for the created user:

```
Invalid password format or unknown hashing algorithm.
```

What should i change ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer fixed it:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/29391122/355641

i guess the use of `get_user_model` was the solution.

Answer (score 4):

There's a special method on the `User`'s manager - [create_user()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.UserManager.create_user), which do exactly what you need to do

Comment: ok, but what if you need to create one web service to create such user ?