# Django REST Framework: creating user does not require password, and password is not saved when sent

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm using DRF to create a simple signup/login application and I am having trouble requiring the password when creating a new user.

I've lurked through SO and the documentation but haven't been able to figure this out.

### serializers.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from rest_framework.serializers import HyperlinkedModelSerializer


class UserSerializer(HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('url', 'username', 'email', 
                  'groups', 'first_name', 'last_name',
                  'date_joined', 'last_login'
                 )
        write_only_fields = ('password',)
```

### views.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User, Group
from rest_framework.authentication import TokenAuthentication
from rest_framework.permissions import IsAuthenticated
from rest_framework.viewsets import ModelViewSet, ReadOnlyModelViewSet
from rest_framework.generics import CreateAPIView
from .serializers import UserSerializer


class UserReadOnlyViewSet(ReadOnlyModelViewSet):
    """
    API endpoint that allows users to be viewed.
    """
    authentication_classes = (TokenAuthentication,)
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)

    queryset = User.objects.all().order_by('-date_joined')
    serializer_class = UserSerializer


class UserCreateView(CreateAPIView):
    """
    API endpoint that allows users to be created.
    """
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
```

### urls.py

```
from django.urls import path, include
from rest_framework import routers
from .views import UserReadOnlyViewSet, UserCreateView

router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'users', UserReadOnlyViewSet)


urlpatterns = [
    path('', include(router.urls)),
    path('signup/', UserCreateView.as_view()),
]
```

I am able to list user(s) at the endpoint `users/` | `users/<pk>/`, and I am able to create a user by posting to `signup/`, with the following JSON data:

```
{
    "username": "new_user",
    "password": "12345678",
    "email": "fulano@dominio.com"
}
```

I am also able to create a user by sending only the `username` in the request body, and I need the password to be required, as is the username.

So, in summary the problems I am having are

1. **The password is not required when posting to `signup/`**
2. **When I send the password is not saved, neither hashed nor in plain-text.**

Thank you.

Comment: did you looked at this [asnwer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29391122/3926995) ? You can do the singup process in the `Serializer` class or by overriding the view.

Comment: Yep. You're right. The solution was to declare the password field in the serializer class definition, using `.set_password` in the `create` method and including it in the fields attribute of `Meta`. Thanks!