# I cannot register a user using Django-Rest-Framework

Tags: python, django, authentication, django-rest-framework, backend

I can't add a new user using Django Rest Framework. Here is my code from **models.py**:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=15, default= None)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, validators=[name_validator])
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, validators=[name_validator])
    email = models.CharField(max_length=100, validators=[mail_validator])
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

As you can see I am using *models.OneToOneField* cause I want to extend the default user to add some more fields.

Bellow is my **serializers.py** file:

```
class ProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        permissions_classes = [
            permissions.AllowAny
        ]
        fields = '__all__'
```

The viewset is the following:

```
class UserViewset(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Profile.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ProfileSerializer
```

When I go to my endpoints and try to add a new user, I cannot put anything in the "user" field:

[Click for image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N5F7H.png)

I am a beginner and it would be of great help.

Thank you!

Comment: You need to have users before you can add it to **Profile** model. You can test this by adding some users before adding profile. Now when you add profile you will get all the available users for adding to the profile.

Comment: But What I want is to create a new user with all those attributes. Not to select from some existing users.

Comment: For that you need **writable nested serializer**. Another method is to override the create method of **user serializer**. Check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/29867704/4901118

Answer (score 0):

you can to this

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=15, default= None)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, validators=[name_validator])
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, validators=[name_validator])
    email = models.CharField(max_length=100, validators=[mail_validator])
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

serializer.py

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = "__all__"

class ProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = UserSerializer(read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = '__all__'
```

views.py

```
class UserViewset(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Profile.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ProfileSerializer
    permission_classes = [permission. AllowAny,]
```

Comment: Please explain how this code dump addresses the problem that the OP had?

Answer (score 0):

When you want to extend the default user to add some more fields, the best way for that is [substituting a custom User model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/auth/customizing/#substituting-a-custom-user-model) by inheritance the AbstractUser model. Using this way, you can CRUD the user easily.