# how to print content inside UserSerializer type - django rest framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Hi I am trying to create user register using django rest frame work. So far I have been following this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/29391122/13240914, and I am still new in django, the thing that I would like to ask is.. is there a way to print content inside UserSerializer type.. here is part of the code

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    password = serializers.CharField(write_only=True)

    def create(self, validated_data):
        print(self)
        print(self.data)
        user = UserModel.objects.create_user(
            username=validated_data['username'],
            password=validated_data['password'],
        )
        return user
```

Here is the result when I print `self`:

```
UserSerializer(context={'request': <rest_framework.request.Request: POST '/create/user/'>, 'format': None, 'view': <face_detector.views.CreateUserView object>}, data={'username': 'hello', 'password': 'hello123456'}):
    username = CharField(help_text='Required. 150 characters or fewer. Letters, digits and @/./+/-/_ only.', max_length=150, validators=[<django.contrib.auth.validators.UnicodeUsernameValidator object>, <UniqueValidator(queryset=User.objects.all())>])
    password = CharField(write_only=True)
```

and when I print `print(self.data)` I only get `{'username': 'hello'}`
so, what I would like to print is all of the request that I have sent from postman, for ex:

```
data={'username': 'hello', 'password': 'hello123456', "detail":"123456789"}
```

Comment: The password field is write_only so will not appear in `data` because `data` is the serialized ("read") representation of the serializer instance. Could you not just print `validated_data`?

Comment: @IainShelvington when I print ```validated_dat```, I get the result {'username': 'hello', 'password': 'hello123456'}, but how if in postman I send something like this: {
   "username":"hello",
   "another trial":"oke",
   "password":"hello123456"
}, is there a way to get all of request that I have sent from postman ?

Comment: Try `self.initial_data`?

Comment: @IainShelvington, I get all of request content (using ```self.initial_data```) , that should be an answer, thank you soooooo much for your help